# Get all row from first table and 1 matching row (column) from another table using JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two table related to image gallery, first table stores albums name and second table store album image, i need to show all albums on one page (albums) and related images on the second page (album-photos)

on first page i have to show Album Name & Image but problem is the album table (Albums) doesnt have any Album related image. so i want to take any image from table (AlbumImages) which has all the images related to album.

I tried below JOIN query it pull all teh matching record from both table while i want only any image related to album so that i can show it on the Album Page

```
  SELECT a.AlbumID,Title,AlbumImageName, Description,AlbumDate,AlbumType FROM Albums a LEFT OUTER JOIN AlbumImages i
  ON a.AlbumID = i.AlbumID
   WHERE AlbumType = 1 
  AND  a.IsVisible=1  AND a.IsActive=1 
   ORDER BY AlbumDate DESC
```

Table Structure

Albums (AlbumID,Title,AlbumDate,AlbumType,IsVisible)
AlbumImages(AlbumImageID,AlbumID,AlbumImageName,ImageCaption,ImageOrder,IsVisible)

How can i simple show details from first table and any image one related to album on album page since Albums Table doesn't store any image related to album in Albums table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` with a random/unspecified ordering, and just retain the "first" image record for each album:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.AlbumID, a.Title, i.AlbumImageName, Description, a.AlbumDate, a.AlbumType,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.AlbumID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM Albums a
    LEFT JOIN AlbumImages i ON a.AlbumID = i.AlbumID
    WHERE AlbumType = 1 AND a.IsVisible = 1 AND a.IsActive = 1
)

SELECT AlbumID, Title, AlbumImageName, Description, AlbumDate, AlbumType
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: i am getting error for this CTE `The column 'AlbumID' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.` not sure to where `AlbumID` is specified multiple times..

Comment: @student Thanks for pointing this out.  Try the updated version, where I explicitly list out the columns in the CTE, including `AlbumID` only once.  This should fix the problem.